# adjust one label in ggplot pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I made this pie chart showing the use of three different kinds of bikes, I put the labels of the total number of rides. However, I'd like to adjust the label of the docked bike over the purple it's a bit hard to read. I can't seem to be able to move it up vertically. Or perhaps I should move all the labels further to the outer edge of the pie chart, but I also don't know how to do that.

```
summary(clean_rides)
   ride_id          rideable_type        started_at                    
 Length:5283970     Length:5283970     Min.   :2022-01-01 00:01:00.00  
 Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:2022-05-29 09:11:21.00  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :2022-07-22 21:04:14.50  
                                       Mean   :2022-07-20 16:39:18.75  
                                       3rd Qu.:2022-09-16 16:17:55.50  
                                       Max.   :2022-12-31 23:59:26.00  
                                                                       
    ended_at                      start_station_name start_station_id   end_station_name  
 Min.   :2022-01-01 00:04:39.00   Length:5283970     Length:5283970     Length:5283970    
 1st Qu.:2022-05-29 09:29:42.00   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Median :2022-07-22 21:21:57.00   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :2022-07-20 16:55:21.08                                                           
 3rd Qu.:2022-09-16 16:35:19.00                                                           
 Max.   :2023-01-01 18:09:37.00                                                           
                                                                                          
 end_station_id       start_lat       start_lng         end_lat         end_lng      
 Length:5283970     Min.   :41.64   Min.   :-87.84   Min.   : 0.00   Min.   :-88.14  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:41.88   1st Qu.:-87.66   1st Qu.:41.88   1st Qu.:-87.66  
 Mode  :character   Median :41.90   Median :-87.64   Median :41.90   Median :-87.64  
                    Mean   :41.90   Mean   :-87.65   Mean   :41.90   Mean   :-87.65  
                    3rd Qu.:41.93   3rd Qu.:-87.63   3rd Qu.:41.93   3rd Qu.:-87.63  
                    Max.   :45.64   Max.   :-73.80   Max.   :42.37   Max.   :  0.00  
                                                                                     
 member_casual           date               month               day                year          
 Length:5283970     Min.   :2022-01-01   Length:5283970     Length:5283970     Length:5283970    
 Class :character   1st Qu.:2022-05-29   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Median :2022-07-22   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                    Mean   :2022-07-20                                                           
                    3rd Qu.:2022-09-16                                                           
                    Max.   :2022-12-31                                                           
                                                                                                 
    day_of_week     ride_length       ride_distance        ride_speed      
 Sunday   :713811   Length:5283970    Min.   :   0.010   Min.   :     0.0  
 Monday   :698799   Class :difftime   1st Qu.:   1.020   1st Qu.:     8.0  
 Tuesday  :734379   Mode  :numeric    Median :   1.680   Median :    10.9  
 Wednesday:749810                     Mean   :   2.289   Mean   :    11.2  
 Thursday :789376                     3rd Qu.:   2.910   3rd Qu.:    14.0  
 Friday   :749275                     Max.   :9817.320   Max.   :420692.1  
 Saturday :848520
```

```
user_type_ride_type <- clean_rides %>% 
  group_by(rideable_type, member_casual) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_rides = n(),
            total_ride_time = sum(ride_length),
            average_ride_time = mean(ride_length)) %>%
  mutate(percentage = case_when(
    member_casual == "casual" ~ round(number_of_rides / sum(number_of_rides) * 100, 0),
    member_casual == "member" ~ round(number_of_rides / sum(number_of_rides) * 100, 0)
  ))


    casual_data <- user_type_ride_type %>% filter(member_casual == "casual")


 ggplot(casual_data, aes(x = "", y = number_of_rides, fill = rideable_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00C19F", "#D7EF16", "#9100B1"),
                    labels = c("classic bike", "electric bike", "docked bike")) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = comma(number_of_rides)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title = "Total Rides by Bike Type for Casual Users",
       fill = "Bike Type",
       caption = "Data Source: Motivate International Inc") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        plot.caption.position = "plot",
        plot.caption = element_text(color = "gray", hjust = 3.8, vjust = 1))
```

I tried adjusting the vjust number of all the labels, but it just kind of spins the labels around clcokwise and leaves a white chunk in the pie chart if the number goes too high.

I also tried just adjusting the docked bike label, but it seems to be blocked, no matter what I set the vjust it doesn't move.

```
ggplot(casual_data, aes(x = "", y = number_of_rides, fill = rideable_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00C19F", "#D7EF16", "#9100B1"),
                    labels = c("classic bike", "electric bike", "docked bike")) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
geom_text(aes(label = comma(number_of_rides)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(data = casual_data[casual_data$rideable_type == "docked bike",],
            aes(x = "", y = number_of_rides, label = comma(number_of_rides)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Marinda_L! Could you please include some data for ```clean_rides```? It is helpful to provide a minimal, working example. Without some example data to work with, in the format you used, we can't replicate the problem or propose a full solution. See here: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I uploaded a summary of the clean_rides data set, does that help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.